# How to make my content movable according to the Material UI drawer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, frontend, jsx

I want to move the content from Form.jsx according to the direction in which the drawer will move. When I click on the menu icon, the Drawer will be expanded but the content inside the body cannot be moved according to the drawer. How to make it enable here?

Before the drawer menu gets clicked:

[image]

After the drawer menu gets clicked:

[image]

Code is below:

> Form.jsx

```
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';

const DrawerHeader = styled('div')(({ theme }) => ({
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    padding: theme.spacing(0, 1),
    ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
}));

export default function Form() {

    return (
        <Box component="main" sx={{ flexGrow: 1, p: 9 }}>
            <DrawerHeader />
            <TextField id="outlined-basic" label="Outlined" variant="outlined" />
            <TextField id="filled-basic" label="Filled" variant="filled" />
            <TextField id="standard-basic" label="Standard" variant="standard" />
        </Box>
    );
};
```

> Drawer.jsx

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { styled, createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import MuiDrawer from '@mui/material/Drawer';
import MuiAppBar from '@mui/material/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@mui/material/Toolbar';
import List from '@mui/material/List';
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Divider from '@mui/material/Divider';
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';
import MenuIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Menu';
import ChevronLeftIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ChevronLeft';
import ChevronRightIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ChevronRight';
import ListItem from '@mui/material/ListItem';
import ListItemButton from '@mui/material/ListItemButton';
import ListItemIcon from '@mui/material/ListItemIcon';
import ListItemText from '@mui/material/ListItemText';
import InboxIcon from '@mui/icons-material/MoveToInbox';
import MailIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Mail';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const drawerWidth = 240;

const openedMixin = (theme) => ({
  width: drawerWidth,
  transition: theme.transitions.create('width', {
    easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
    duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
  }),
  overflowX: 'hidden',
});

const closedMixin = (theme) => ({
  transition: theme.transitions.create('width', {
    easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
    duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
  }),
  overflowX: 'hidden',
  width: `calc(${theme.spacing(7)} + 1px)`,
  [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
    width: `calc(${theme.spacing(8)} + 1px)`,
  },
});

const DrawerHeader = styled('div')(({ theme }) => ({
  display: 'flex',
  alignItems: 'center',
  justifyContent: 'flex-end',
  padding: theme.spacing(0, 1),
  // necessary for content to be below app bar
  ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
}));

const AppBar = styled(MuiAppBar, {
  shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== 'open',
})(({ theme, open }) => ({
  zIndex: theme.zIndex.drawer + 1,
  background: "fb8500",
  transition: theme.transitions.create(['width', 'margin'], {
    easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
    duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
  }),
  ...(open && {
    marginLeft: drawerWidth,
    width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(['width', 'margin'], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
    }),
  }),
}));

const Drawer = styled(MuiDrawer, { shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== 'open' })(
  ({ theme, open }) => ({
    width: drawerWidth,
    flexShrink: 0,
    whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
    boxSizing: 'border-box',
    ...(open && {
      ...openedMixin(theme),
      '& .MuiDrawer-paper': openedMixin(theme),
    }),
    ...(!open && {
      ...closedMixin(theme),
      '& .MuiDrawer-paper': closedMixin(theme),
    }),
  }),
);

export default function MiniDrawer() {

  const PageList = [
    {
      id: 1,
      text: "Add new Donee",
      to: "/form",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      text: "Donees",
      to: "/view",
    },
  ];

  // const theme = useTheme();
  const theme = createTheme({
    palette: {
      primary: {
        // Purple and green play nicely together.
        main: '#ffca3a',
      },
      secondary: {
        // This is green.A700 as hex.
        main: '#11cb5f',
      },
    },
  });

  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleDrawerOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleDrawerClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Box sx={{ display: 'flex' }}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <AppBar position="fixed" open={open}>
          <Toolbar>
            <IconButton
              color="inherit"
              aria-label="open drawer"
              onClick={handleDrawerOpen}
              edge="start"
              sx={{
                marginRight: 5,
                ...(open && { display: 'none' }),
              }}
            >
              <MenuIcon />
            </IconButton>
            <Typography variant="h6" noWrap component="div">
              Compassion Lanka Data Entry
            </Typography>
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
        <Drawer variant="permanent" open={open}>
          <DrawerHeader>
            <IconButton onClick={handleDrawerClose}>
              {theme.direction === 'rtl' ? <ChevronRightIcon /> : <ChevronLeftIcon />}
            </IconButton>
          </DrawerHeader>
          <Divider />
          <List>
            {PageList.map((text, index) => (
              <ListItem key={text.id} disablePadding sx={{ display: 'block' }}>
                <ListItemButton
                  sx={{
                    minHeight: 48,
                    justifyContent: open ? 'initial' : 'center',
                    px: 2.5,
                  }}
                  component={Link} to={text.to}
                >
                  <ListItemIcon
                    sx={{
                      minWidth: 0,
                      mr: open ? 3 : 'auto',
                      justifyContent: 'center',
                    }}
                  >
                    {index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}
                  </ListItemIcon>
                  <ListItemText primary={text.text} sx={{ opacity: open ? 1 : 0 }} />
                </ListItemButton>
              </ListItem>
            ))}
          </List>
          <Divider />
        </Drawer>
      </Box>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set margin or padding of `<Box component="main">` to the width of the drawer.